# Not able to display "output1" from document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "L1: " L1.DisplayAll();

Tags: javascript

As it says in the title I am unable to display another div for the life 
of me. Please review and enlighten me why I am not able to get " id=output1" to show?

The following is the html:

```
    <input type="button" value="Insert Queue Length" onClick="InitializeQueue();" />
    <br/>
    <div id="output">
    <br/>
    <div id="output1">
    <br/>
```

The following is the javascript with function and methods for queueing

```
    function Queue(){
        var count = 0;
        var head = null;
        var tail = null;
        this.GetCount = function(){
            return count;
        }

    this.Enqueue = function (data) {
        //fill queue
        var node = {
            data: data,

            next: head
        };
        if (head === null) {
            tail = node;
        }
        head = node;
        count++;
    }

    this.Dequeue = function () {
//if queue is empty, returns null
        if (count === 0) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            var current = head;
            var previous = null;
            while (current.next) {
                previous = current;
                current = current.next;
            }
            if (count > 1) {
                previous.next = null;
                tail = previous;
            }
            else {
                head = null;
                tail = null;
            }

            count--;
        }
    }

    this.DisplayAll = function () {
        if (head === null) {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            var arr = new Array();
            var current = head;

            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                arr[i] = current.data;
                current = current.next;
            }
        arr = arr.reverse();
            return arr;
        }
    }

      }
```

This Creates a Linked List and Adds Nodes to it

```
    var L1 = new Queue();

    function InitializeQueue() {
        var iteration = 0; 
        var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("QueueLength").value);
        for(i = 2; i <= y; i++){ 
            L1.Enqueue(i);  
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "L1: "+     L1.DisplayAll();
            }
            L1.Dequeue();
            //For some reason this wont display, but the dequeue seems to work properly
            document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "L1: "+   L1.DisplayAll();


    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't need to close the divs? If this is not the problem, please create a fiddle with a working example.

```
<input type="button" value="Insert Queue Length" onClick="InitializeQueue();" />
<br/>
<div id="output"></div>
<br/>
<div id="output1"></div>
<br/>
```

Comment: well that's what i get for going at this code for 5 hours, and get stuck for 20 min and cry wolf, sorry for taking anyone's time. Thank you Niels!